# Change Date Settings in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

The default Spotfire Work Week starts on Sunday and ends on Saturday.

I would like to adjust that default value so it starts on Monday and ends on Sunday.  I would also like to adjust the work week value itself and my company's work week is one less than the default Spotfire value.

So if I'm looking at 2016, work week 1 starts Monday January 4th and ends Sunday January 10th.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using DayOfWeek()?

Comment: So, I've been doing more digging.  If I take today's date (9/12/2016), the Week function gives me "38" when today is the start of work week 37.  If I take today's day, the WorkWeek function gives me "201637" which is correct.  Our work week starts at 7pm Sunday and ends 18:59:59 the next Sunday.  I would like to adjust WorkWeek to compensate for those 4 hours if possible to do without creating a formula.  I see on other questions that I can adjust the Regional Settings or something in the Administration Manager, but I can't find those places.

Comment: You will have to use a calculated column if you can't change the regional settings on your Local machine and web server. But neither setting will account for a 4 hour change for work week without conflicting your GMT offset. Let us know if you need help with creating a calculated DateTime column with your logic. It's definitely the path of least resistance.

Comment: WorkWeek appears to be working correctly outside of those 4 hours, but I think you're right about having to do the calculated column to make up for it.  No worries.  Thanks for your help!